# MySQL Prune old rows to one per day

Tags: mysql

I have a huge MySQL Table, and it grows around 90 rows per second, every 4 hours 1.3 million rows gets dumped in there with the timestamp

```
user(varchar)   | created_at(timestamp)
----------------------------
user 1          | 2016-01-27 08:00:00
user 2          | 2016-01-27 08:00:00
user 3          | 2016-01-27 08:00:00
...
user 1          | 2016-01-27 12:00:00
user 2          | 2016-01-27 12:00:00
```

etc... What is the best approach for pruning data older than a month to only have one row per day?

There is always rows at 00:00 so I was thinking something along the lines of

`created_at >= date + 00:00 and created_at < date + 19:59`

or

`select user, max(created_at) from table where created_at = date group by username`

Comment: what do you mean by only have one row per day?

Comment: So every 4 hours I get some data for all users, but I dont need it that fine after a month, just one per day, so ideally just keep the first import on the day. The mins a seconds are always 0, as it is the time of the import start, its done in PHP as `date('Y-m-d H:00:00')`

Comment: you could actually use [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)  on mysql, you can schedule those events to delete a certain table and run that event everyday at specific time

Comment: use limit 1 or group by created_at to keep the single record.

Comment: I think I've managed it, takes an age to run though `select count(id) from teamsarchive where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)  and HOUR(created_at) = 00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I've had a bit of a play so I'll post this for anyone else wanting to prune their data.

`created_at` must be a `TIMESTAMP`

```
delete from `table` where `created_at` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and HOUR(created_at) = 00
```

This will delete all rows with the hour set to 00, but if you need more flexibility you can do

```
delete from `table` where `created_at` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and HOUR(created_at) between 0 and 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a large amount of data, you may want to use partitions to manage the data, as running delete statements with filter on large tables can take very long time. When you create partitions by month, removing a partition is super fast. But this will delete data in that month, so you may need to store the user summary in another table before removing a partition.